# Pandas DataFrame including three numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to make a pandas DataFrame with the contents of three diferents numpy arrays.

1. valor_norte;value of a variable  numpy.ndarray
2. valor_este;value of a variable  numpy.ndarray
3. dtime  numpy.ndarray

   valor_norte

   array([-0.14300001, -0.10600001, -0.075     , -0.054     , -0.041     ,
          -0.035     , -0.03      , -0.017     ,  0.007     ,  0.038     ,
           0.07      ,  0.09100001,  0.098     ,  0.09      ,  0.07300001,
           0.05      ,  0.023     , -0.004     , -0.023     , -0.03      ,
          -0.025     , -0.014     , -0.003     ,  0.004     ], dtype=float32)

   valor_este

   array([-0.07600001, -0.078     , -0.071     , -0.06500001, -0.062     ,
          -0.063     , -0.07      , -0.089     , -0.108     , -0.12400001,
          -0.134     , -0.123     , -0.093     , -0.05      , -0.009     ,
           0.016     ,  0.023     ,  0.009     , -0.022     , -0.059     ,
          -0.09200001, -0.11300001, -0.12100001, -0.11400001], dtype=float32)

   dtime

   array([datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 0, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 1, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 2, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 3, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 4, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 5, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 6, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 7, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 8, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 9, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 10, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 11, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 12, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 13, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 14, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 15, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 16, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 17, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 18, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 19, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 20, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 21, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 22, 30),
          datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 23, 30)], dtype=object)

code

```
tabla_datos = pd.DataFrame(valor_norte,valor_este,dtime)
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 24), indices imply (24, 24)

tabla_datos = pd.DataFrame(valor_norte,valor_este)
```

but the dataframe uses valor_norte as index

```
indice = dtime.tolist()
tabla_datos = pd.DataFrame(valor_norte,valor_este, index=indice)
```

returns

```
KeyError: datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 0, 30)
```

How do I make a df using index = dtime and columns; valor_este, valor_norte ?

Comment: could you post your numpy arrays?

Comment: array([-0.14300001, -0.10600001, -0.075     , -0.054     , -0.041     ,
       -0.035     , -0.03      , -0.017     ,  0.007     ,  0.038     ,
        0.07      ,  0.09100001,  0.098     ,  0.09      ,  0.07300001,
        0.05      ,  0.023     , -0.004     , -0.023     , -0.03      ,
       -0.025     , -0.014     , -0.003     ,  0.004     ], dtype=float32)

Comment: dtime
array([datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 0, 30),
       datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 1, 30),
       datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 2, 30),
       datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 3, 30),
       datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 4, 30),
       datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 5, 30),
       datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 6, 30),.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. I'm using a dict format for the data

```
pd.DataFrame({'norte' : valor_norte, 'este' : valor_este},index=dtime)
```

Comment: I tried, but doesn´t work    *** TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'index'

Comment: @kamome Please edit your question to include your 3 ndarrays (or a sample of each one) so we can reproduce the data.

Comment: Are the variables of a netCDF file